# Including print size of my layout in label in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, layouts, qgis-print-layouts

I want to include the print size of my layout (e.g. "A3") as part of a label on the map, how can I write an expression to capture this information automatically?

I am using QGIS 3.12.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Usually you'd either have a template for the usual sheet sizes, or you'd build the layout from scratch, where you'd have to enter the sheet size anyway - so why use an expression? Could you explain your workflow a bit more detailed?

Comment: Yes I am intending to use my layout to create templates, these will then be used to generate pdf maps and I want these to have a label such as "1:5000 when printed at A3". Because I will produce the pdf at A3 size but cannot control how users might print the pdf eg they may print it onto an A4 page then just to have scale 1:5000 would be incorrect. Hope this explains!

Comment: This is why you include a scalebar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When in print layout you can add a new Label to the layout and in the item properties click on insert an expression. You could then try something like this to display the page height and then width separated by a comma:

`[% @layout_pageheight  ||', '|| @layout_pagewidth %]`

**Note:** You can also add a numeric scale by first clicking on the scale icon in the map layout screen,

[image]

any changing the style to numeric. This will be dynamic and will change when map scale is changed or map dimensions , and will be in the form you mention above (e.g. 1:5000).

[image]

**If you want to display page size (e.g. A4)**

You will need to write a custom expression similar to this below

```
[%CASE                                                                    
   WHEN  @layout_pagewidth  = 297 AND  @layout_pageheight = 210 THEN 'A4' 
   WHEN  @layout_pagewidth  = xx AND  @layout_pageheight = xx THEN 'A3' 
   ELSE 'Custom'                                                         
END%]
```

Comment: wow, how did you make that video?

Comment: @HansErren created a GIF with ScreenToGif and uploaded it when writing my answer

Comment: Thanks - is there a way to show the size eg A3 rather than the dimensions?

Comment: The only way I believe that is possible is to write a custom expression where if certain dimension criteria are met you output the page size (e.g. A3, A4 or Custom where the criteria is not met)

Comment: See example in edited answer above